# Sidekiq + Rails Model Generating Extra Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, console, sidekiq, worker

I'm having an issue with my scheduled text messages. I run a rake task that checks to see if a text message should be put into a Sidekiq queue. The record is processed (the text is sent) but a new empty record is generated and the sentstatus is not updated to "true".

**send_scheduled_text.rake**

```
require_relative '../../app/workers/send_text_worker'

namespace :send_scheduled_text do

  task:texts => :environment do

   TextMessage.all.each do |text_message|
      if text_message.sentstatus == false
        if (Date.today == text_message.scheduled_date) && (Time.now.hour >= text_message.scheduled_time.hour)
        # Sidekiq code: 
        SendTextWorker.perform_async(text_message.id)
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

**send_text_worker.rb**

```
class SendTextWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(text_message_id)
    text = TextMessage.find(text_message_id)
    text.send_text_message(text.content, text.phone)
  end
end
```

**text_message.rb**

```
require 'twilio-ruby'
require 'date'

class TextMessage < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :client, dependent: :destroy
  belongs_to :step, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :coach_emails

  before_save :grab_phone

  def grab_phone
    self.phone = phone
  end

  def send_text_message(message, phone)

    twilio_sid = ENV["TWILIO_ACCT_SID"]
    twilio_token = ENV["TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN"]
    twilio_phone_number = ENV["TWILIO_PHONE_NUMBER"]

    begin
      @twilio_client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(twilio_sid, twilio_token)

      @twilio_client.account.sms.messages.create(
        :from => "+1#{twilio_phone_number}",
        :to => phone,
        :body => message)

      rescue Twilio::REST::RequestError => e
        puts e.message
    end

   if e != "400" || e != "500"
      self.sentstatus = true
   end

    self.save!
  send  
send
```

**Rails console: before rake task is called**
(sentstatus is false)

```
irb(main):001:0> TextMessage.all
  TextMessage Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "text_messages".* FROM "text_messages"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<TextMessage id: 164, client_id: nil, content: "Testing Sidekiq processing", incoming_message: false, created_at: "2015-02-02 04:43:29", updated_at: "2015-02-02 04:43:29", scheduled_date: "2015-02-01", sentstatus: false, step_id: 4, phone: "+14127364161", scheduled_time: "2000-01-01 14:00:00">]>
```

**Rails console: After rake task is called**
(sentstatus is false, should be true. I also have this new bizarre empty record)

```
irb(main):001:0> TextMessage.all
  TextMessage Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "text_messages".* FROM "text_messages"
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<TextMessage id: 164, client_id: nil, content: "Testing Sidekiq processing", incoming_message: false, created_at: "2015-02-02 04:43:29", updated_at: "2015-02-02 04:43:29", scheduled_date: "2015-02-01", sentstatus: false, step_id: 4, phone: "+14127364161", scheduled_time: "2000-01-01 14:00:00">, 
#<TextMessage id: 165, client_id: nil, content: nil, incoming_message: nil, created_at: "2015-02-02 04:45:24", updated_at: "2015-02-02 04:45:24", scheduled_date: nil, sentstatus: true, step_id: nil, phone: nil, scheduled_time: nil>]>
```

I have a feeling this is a Sidekiq nuance that I'm missing. Thanks for any thoughts!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up moving my model logic to my worker. Presto -- timing works and I'm not generating any extra nil records.